# Google doc Python API: How to modify the content of a specific cell

Tags: python, google-docs-api

Thanks for you help & time, here is my code, I am accessing a specific cell of a table and my goal is to modify the text context of this specific cell - by that I mean to overwrite the existing text in that cell with a new string value. How do I do that?

```
def main():
    
    credentials = get_creds()
    service = build("docs", "v1", credentials=credentials).documents()
    properties_req = service.get(documentId=REQ_DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
    doc_content_req = properties_req.get('body').get('content')
    properties_des = service.get(documentId=DES_DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
    doc_content_des = properties_des.get('body').get('content')
    reqs = find_requirements(doc_content_req)
    for (req, row) in zip(reqs, req_table.get('tableRows')):
        loc = search_structural_elements(doc_content_des, req)
        cell = get_cell(row, design_col)
        print(f"Requirement {req} is located in section {loc} of the design doc.")
        print(cell) # Need to modify the text content of this specific cell
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect as the images?

Comment: Tanaike san, 

Input is a M x N table (M rows N cols). Output is a M x N table. The difference is in the text content of cells in the table, which our Python script overwrites.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Input is a M x N table (M rows N cols). Output is a M x N table. The difference is in the text content of cells in the table, which our Python script overwrites.`, I cannot image your situation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot understand about your question soon.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike san, lets says the input is 2 x 2 table and output is also 2 x 2 table. Suppose input 1st row is "hello", "world" and input 2nd row is "imagine", "hope".

Now I want the input table to be overwritten such that the output table 1st row is
"hope", "imagine" and 2nd row is "world", "hello"

Arrigato

Comment: Hi there @Ukkadam! I understand that you want to modify the value of a cell in a Doc table, is that correct? If not please show some examples of the initial/final situation.

Comment: Yes @Jacques-GuzelHeron, you are right, I want to modify the value (the text associated) with a cell in a particular Doc table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify the contents of a particular cell by using the [`Documents.batchUpdate()`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) tool. First and foremost I strongly recommend you to familiarize yourself with the [`Table`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#table) structure inside a Doc. There you can see how the table is first declared, then divided in rows and later formatted with some styles. After you write the desired change in the desired cell (from the desired row), then you can use `Documents.batchUpdate()` and reach your goal.

As a tip, I want to add that you can run a small trick to easily find the desired cell. This operation can help you manage your first cell edit easily. First you will need to open the Doc in a browser, then you have to write a recognizable string (like `123ABC`) in the desired cell. After that you could use [`Documents.get()`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) to receive the Document object. You can search for the `123ABC` string without difficulty in that object, change it to the desired value, and use that object as a template for the batch update. Please ask me any additional questions about this answer.